# Partial JSON serialization of REST response objects in Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc, jackson

A lot of similar questions have been asked on this site so far without satisfactory answers, so I am going to try to focus this question a bit to get an answer.

Here is the goal, I would like my Spring MVC 4 (with Spring HATEOAS) web service to accept the following requests and respond with the appropriately serialized entities:

```
GET http://myapp/api/people
==> [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Joe",
        "email": "joe@domain.com",
        "links": [...]
    },
    {...etc}]

GET http://myapp/api/people?fields=id,email
==> [{
        "id": 1,
        "email": "joe@domain.com"
    },
    {...etc}]
```

I'd like to preserve my domain models in my controller classes and do the field filtering during the JSON serialization, so I am wrapping my response in a simple class with a single field to store the fields to use in the filtering:

```
public class RestResponseEnvelope<T> {

    private Set<String> fieldSet;
    private T entity;

    public RestResponseEnvelope(T entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    public T getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }

    public Set<String> getFieldSet() {
        return fieldSet;
    }

    public void setFieldSet(Set<String> fieldSet) {
        this.fieldSet = fieldSet;
    }

    public void setFields(String fields) {
        Set<String> fieldSet = new HashSet<>();
        if (fields != null) {
            for (String field : fields.split(",")) {
                fieldSet.add(field);
            }
        }
        this.fieldSet = fieldSet;
    }
}
```

So my controller methods wind up looking something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<RestResponseEnvelope<Resources<<Resource<Person>>>> findAllPeople(
        @RequestParam(value = "fields", required = false) String fields
){

    List<Resource<Person>> peopleResourceList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person person: personService.findAllPeople()){
        Resource<Person> resource = new Resource<>(person);
        resource.add(link...);
        peopleResourceList.add(resource);
    }

    Resources<Resource<Person>> resources = new Resources<>(personResourceList);
    resources.add(link...);

    RestResponseEnvelope<Resources<Resource<Person>>> responseEnvelope = new RestResponseEnvelope<>(resources);
    responseEnvelope.setFields(fields);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseEnvelope, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

To perform the filtering, I have tried to create a custom `HttpMessageConverter` by extending Jackson's `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` so that it identifies `RestResponseEnvelope` objects and uses their `fieldList` to apply a `filterOutAllExcept` filter:

```
@Component
public class FilteringJackson2HttpMessageConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    private boolean prefixJson = false;

    @Override
    public void setPrefixJson(boolean prefixJson) {
        this.prefixJson = prefixJson;
        super.setPrefixJson(prefixJson);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object object, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = getObjectMapper();
        JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = objectMapper.getFactory().createGenerator(outputMessage.getBody());

        try { 
            if (this.prefixJson) {
                jsonGenerator.writeRaw("{} && ");
            }
            if (object instanceof RestResponseEnvelope){
                Set<String> fieldSet = ((RestResponseEnvelope) object).getFieldSet();
                Object entity = ((RestResponseEnvelope) object).getEntity();
                if (fieldSet != null && !fieldSet.isEmpty()) {
                    objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(CellLine.class, PropertyFilterMixin.class);
                    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
                            .addFilter("filterPropertiesByName",
                                    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(fieldSet));
                    objectMapper.setFilters(filters);
                } 
                objectMapper.writeValue(jsonGenerator, entity);
            } else {
                objectMapper.writeValue(jsonGenerator, object);
            }
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e){
            throw new HttpMessageNotWritableException("Could not write JSON: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

@JsonFilter("filterPropertiesByName")
class PropertyFilterMixin { }
```

I have played around with this setup and have had mixed results.  When a request for filtered fields works correctly, a subsequent request for all fields will return the objects filtered again.  Other times the filtering does not work, or just filters out everything.

I'd like to be able to take a list of requested fields and return the serialized objects with only those fields remaining, ideally without having to do the annotation mixin, but I am completely stumped as to how to accomplish this.  Will my filtering scheme here properly leave the nested attributes fields when the top-level object being serialized is the wrapper or `Resource` objects?  Is it possible to get request parameters from within the context of the JSON serialization process, so that I could do away with the wrapper class?

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimentation, I have found a solution that appears to be doing what I want it to.  First, I annotated my domain model classes with a generic filter annotation:

```
@JsonFilter("fieldFilter")
public class Person {
    ...
}
```

I then updated my message converter to eliminate the annotation mixin and always register this filter with my `ObjectMapper`, but the filtering changes to include everything if my field set parameter is not present:

```
@Component
public class FilteringJackson2HttpMessageConverter extends MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

    private boolean prefixJson = false;

    @Override
    public void setPrefixJson(boolean prefixJson) {
        this.prefixJson = prefixJson;
        super.setPrefixJson(prefixJson);
    }

    @Override
    protected void writeInternal(Object object, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = getObjectMapper();
        JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = objectMapper.getFactory().createGenerator(outputMessage.getBody());

        try {

            if (this.prefixJson) {
                jsonGenerator.writeRaw("{} && ");
            }

            if (object instanceof RestResponseEnvelope) {
                Object entity = ((RestResponseEnvelope) object).getEntity();
                Set<String> fieldSet = ((RestResponseEnvelope) object).getFieldSet();
                if (fieldSet != null && !fieldSet.isEmpty()) {
                    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("fieldFilter",
                                SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept(fieldSet)).setFailOnUnknownId(false);
                    objectMapper.setFilters(filters);
                } else {
                    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("fieldFilter", 
                            SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept()).setFailOnUnknownId(false);
                    objectMapper.setFilters(filters);
                }
                objectMapper.writeValue(jsonGenerator, entity);

            } else if (object == null){
                jsonGenerator.writeNull();
            } else {
                objectMapper.writeValue(jsonGenerator, object);
            }

        } catch (JsonProcessingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new HttpMessageNotWritableException("Could not write JSON: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

This seems to be doing the job, but it would be nice to not have to wrap my domain model objects in another class in order to pass the filterable fields from my controller to the JSON serializer, but it's a small sacrifice I can live with.